# Stirling proof guidance

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like some guidances:

Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^nn!}{n^n} = 0$$

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Are you trying to *use* Stirling's approximation in there, or are you trying to establish a upper bound *for* Stirling there?

Comment: guidance tells us the use of Stirling's approximation is useful in the proof.

Comment: OK, then Stirling's approximation says that $n! \sim (n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$.  See what happens to the argument of the limit when you substitute that expression in for $n!$.

Comment: thank you. so, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n * \sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n} = 0$$. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Plugging this equivalent in our sequence, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n n!}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use a direct argument that doesn't require Stirling's formula.

If you consider the ratio of successive terms you get:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \frac{n^n}{2^n n!} = 2\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}
$$

The limit of this ratio is $2/e<1$, so each ratio is less than, say $4/5$ for suitably large $n$.  Then you have a fixed $N$ such that $a_{N+n} \le (4/5)^n a_N$, for all $n$, and thus the sequence converges to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Firstly, separate off $2n/n$.  Then  $2(2n-2),4(2n-4)$ and so on are all less than $n^2$, and $2(2n-2)/n^2\to0$.

Comment: Doesn't the denominator need to be $n^{2n}$ for this to work?

Comment: No because you only have (n-1)/2 pairs of even numbers.